# angualr2: where to declare model to ngModule

Tags: angular

In Angular2rc6, my module is as below where AppComponent, AppService, Point is a component, injectable service and data model:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { AppService }  from './app.service';
import { Point }  from './point.model';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule 
  ],
  providers: [
    AppService
  ],
  declarations: [ 
    AppComponent, Point
  ],  
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The page throws error when model `Point` is added to `declaration`.

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show us the `point.model.ts` file?

Comment: Point should just not be in the declarations. Those are for directives and pipes.

Comment: What is `Point` supposed to be or to do? Why did you add it to declarations?

Comment: thanks guys. i should not add normal class to ngModule

Answer (score 0):

remove point.ts file from declaration section. model not necessary to have in declaration section